# Making Gradle notice new repositories, or: Gradle equivalent of Maven's -U / --update-snapshots

Tags: gradle, ivy

I have a Gradle project with some dependencies that turned out not to be in Maven central. I tracked them down in the Typesafe repo and added

```
maven {
    url 'http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/repo'
}
```

to my `build.gradle` file, but Gradle continued to report the dependencies missing.

I guessed fairly quickly that what I was looking at was the equivalent of Maven's *failure to find X in Y was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted* but there wasn't any obvious way (cf `mvn -U`) to tell Gradle to un-cache that failure.

Eventually I tried adding `{changing = true}` to that family of dependencies, which apparently told Gradle to try those again, and it found them just fine. I suppose I could also have blown away my whole artifact cache. But it seems like there should be a faster way to fix this. Is there an easy way to either:

1. force Gradle to re-check for missing dependencies, or
2. force Gradle to notice that new repositories have been added, and that it might want to try looking in those instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The equivalent to `mvn -U` is `gradle --refresh-dependencies`. Type `gradle -h` to see all command line options.